# New child window under a different parent in javascript

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have 2 different application server URLs.
There is a link on a page of first application and on click on this link I have to open a new window using href link( maybe window.open()) under second  application(not a new tab or child window on same parent).
The parent window should be second URL while click on the link on a page of first URL.
It should be a popup window.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Windows in the browser have an `.opener()` property based on the window that opened them, but a popup window doesn't have a parent (unless it's a frame of some type, in which case it's not a popup window).  All popup windows are top level windows that are ordered on screen based on when they were opened and which window was last active.  By default now, lots of browsers puts new windows into tabs by default.  So, what exactly are you trying to accomplish.  Rather than talking about a parent, please describe what goal you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have 2 applications running independently.
say http://ky664plp:20000/index.html(Exalead) and http://ky664plp:8080/enovia(Enovia). Both the applications are opened in IE8.0 in 2 tabs.
Now there is a link in Exalead page(first tab) which points to a child url of Enovia(http://ky664plp:8080/enovia/navigator.jsp).If I will click on this link it should open a popup under the second tab(Enovia).

Answer (score 0):

You can control whether a new window is created or not by changing the [strWindowName parameter to window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open)

For an [anchor you can use the target attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a) and provide a [browsing context name](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/datatypes.html#common.data.browsing-context-name-or-keyword)